# Swift Combine custom Publisher: Storing a reference to an array of Subscribers?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to write a custom Combine `Publisher` that will send decibel and timestamps from an `AVAudioEngine` tap. After going through numerous tutorials and the WWDC videos, I *still* can't find an example of how a `Publisher` keeps track of the `Subscriber`s that have subscribed to it.

```
public typealias AudioVolume = Double

public struct AudioVolumePublisher: Publisher {
    public typealias Output = AudioVolume
    public typealias Failure = Error
}

public class AudioVolumeSubscription<S: Subscriber>: NSObject, Subscription {
    private var subscriber: S?
    public var combineIdentifier = CombineIdentifier()

    public init(for subscriber: S) {
        self.subscriber = subscriber
    }

    public func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
        ...
    }

    public func cancel() {
        subscriber = nil
    }
}
```

I assume that the `AudioVolumePublisher` should store a list of its active subscribers, but adding a property like

```
var subscribers = [S]()
```

won't compile because `Subscriber` has associated types. Is this even the right approach to handling `Subscriber`s, and if so, what's the best way to store them? Is type erasure my only practical option?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at how [OpenCombine](https://github.com/broadwaylamb/OpenCombine) implements the operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to achieve your goal with either [`CurrentValueSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) or [`PassthroughSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject).

Assuming this is the shape you are sending:

```
struct AudioVolume {
  let decimal: Decimal
  let timestamp: TimeStamp
}
```

instantiate subject

```
let audioPublisher = PassthroughSubject<AudioVolume, Never>()
```

whenever you need to publish a new value:

```
let audioVolume = AudioVolume(....)
audioPublisher.send(audioVolume)
```

whenever you need to subscribe to the publisher:

```
audioPublisher
  .sink { audioVolume in
    // do something with audioVolume
  }
  .store(in: &cancellables) // retain the subscription in cancellables as long as you want to remain subscribed
```

Comment: How would this work with multiple `Subscriber`s, though? Can I simply call `audioPublisher.sink()` multiple times? `Publisher` is a protocol, so it can't keep track of subscribers itself, but `sink()`'s implementation must be doing something to keep the connection active.

Comment: And what would the `cancellables`'s type be?

Comment: @NRitH PassthroughSubject is a class, it has reference type semantics, if you subscribe multiple subscribers to it, it just keeps on ticking, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Yes you can subscribe as many times as you want using `sink` or any other Combine operator. `cancellables` is type `Set<AnyCancellable>`.